# PutMongoRecord cannot access filename

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I have a simple flow setup in Nifi:

- GetFile picks up CSV files from a directory
- PutMongoRecord stores them in a MongoDB collection (using a CSVReader)

I want to put the records into a collection whose name is derived from the filename: `${filename:substringBefore('.csv')}`. My problem is that I can't seem to get the PutMongoRecord processor to read the filename. Every time, I get the same error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 73: 'Invalid namespace specified 'xxx.'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Invalid namespace specified 'xxx.'", "code" : 73, "codeName" : "InvalidNamespace" }
```

If I try hard-coding a collection name, it works. It also works with ${hostname()}. Since the processor is connected to the "success" output of GetFile, why isn't it reading the filename?

NOTE: I have tested this with a LogAttribute processor: a `filename`attribute is indeed present. I have tried various other attributes, but none seem to produce anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug till NiFi 1.6.0 and it is recently fixed. Take a look at [NIFI-5197](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5197). It will be released in NiFi 1.7.0 which, I believe, will be available in a couple of weeks.

If it is an urgent need, write to the dev@nifi.apache.org and it is possible to get the patch for this.

Comment: OK, thanks! Where can I find out when the next release will be?

Comment: Announcement will be made on the mailing lists. You can subscribe to the users mailing list: https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html